# PHP Date Formatting from MySQL Fatched Datetime

Tags: php, date, datetime, formatting

Can anyone please help?
I have searched many website (including stackoverflow) but can't find my exact answer.

It may be so easy, but I need to know.

> 2014-11-21 18:49:55

I need to convert it to

> 6:49 PM, 21th November, 2014

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: What have you done so far yourself? A simple use of `strtotime()` and `date()` should fix this for you. A more elegant way is using `DateTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$date = "2014-11-21 18:49:55";
echo date('g:i A, dS F Y', strtotime($date));
```

Output:

```
6:49 PM, 21st November 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
$date = "2014-11-21 18:49:55";
echo date('g:i A, jS F, Y', strtotime($date));
```

Output -

```
6:49 PM, 21st November, 2014
```

Comment: Can't you write your own answer?

Comment: You updated it with the `S` and the `strtotime()` which i already had. And it looks almost identical with the variable name and the text like: "Output:"...

Comment: haha.. `s` was already there. And first i have added the format then added the strtotime.. lolz...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$providedTime = '2014-11-21 18:49:55';
$newTime = strtotime($providedTime);
echo date('g:i A, dS F Y', $newTime);
?>
```

[Working example][1]

We can use PHP's [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to get the provided date in required format.

the `date()` function has various parameters and we can use nice use of them.

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$originalDate = "2014-11-21 18:49:55";
$newDate1 = date("g:i A,", strtotime($originalDate));
$newDate2 = date("d", strtotime($originalDate));
$newDate3 = date("F, Y", strtotime($originalDate));
echo $newDate1.' '.$newDate2.'th '.$newDate3;
```